# React Formik with YUP validation error messages - Show all at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am using Formik and YUP in React.js and with my password validation I want to show all of the error messages at once, and then gradually removing them as the user matches the validation.

So the question is how do I show all error messages and then gradually removing them as the user match the criterias:

- At least 12 characters long
- Mix of uppercase and lowercase letters
- At least one digit (0-9)
- At least one special character (!%&@#$^*?_~.,)

```
const userSchema = Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string()
   .min(12, 'At least 12 characters long')
   .matches(/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])/, "Mix of uppercase and lowercase letters")
   .matches(/[0-9]/, "At least one digit (0-9)")
   .matches(/[!%&@#$^*?_~.,]/, 'At least one special character (!%&@#$^*?_~.,)')
});

 const passwordAlertClass = errors.password && touched.password ? styles.alert : "";


div className={styles.field_outer_wrapper}>
  <div className={styles.field_inner_wrapper}>
    <label htmlFor="password" className={styles.label}>
      Password*
    </label>
 <Field
 name="password"
id="password"
type="password"
className={combineClasses(
tyles.text_field,
passwordAlertClass
)}
/>
 </div>
```

I could not find an option inside the YUP libary to match the behaviour I want.

I did try the

```
abortEarly: false
```

Comment: There is an open issue about this, there is no easy way for now: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/243

Comment: Why you want to show all error messages initially? 
It is against any UI concept in form validation.